# Installing Doctrine extensions in a Symfony 2 project causes Fatal Error

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine-extensions, stofdoctrineextensions

Here is the problem : I don't succeed to install doctrine extensions with symphony 2, especially timestampable. I follow [this tutorial](http://0hlsson.se/2011/07/24/symfony-2-and-doctrineextensions/)

How I proceed :

I add this lines in deps file :

```
[gedmo-doctrine-extensions]
   git=http://github.com/l3pp4rd/DoctrineExtensions.git

[Stof-DoctrineExtensionsBundle]
   git=https://github.com/stof/StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle.git
   target=/bundles/Stof/DoctrineExtensionsBundle
```

Then I enter the line

```
./bin/vendors install --reinstall
```

All is fine.

Then I activate extensions in concerned files

```
# config.yml
stof_doctrine_extensions:
    default_locale: fr_FR
    orm:
        default:
            timestampable: true


# AppKernel.php    
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel;
use Symfony\Component\Config\Loader\LoaderInterface;

class AppKernel extends Kernel
{
    public function registerBundles()
    {
        $bundles = array(
            [...]
            new Stof\DoctrineExtensionsBundle\StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle(),
            [...]
        );

# autoload.php
use Symfony\Component\ClassLoader\UniversalClassLoader;
use Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationRegistry;

$loader = new UniversalClassLoader();
$loader->registerNamespaces(array(
    'Gedmo'            => __DIR__.'/../vendor/gedmo-doctrine-extensions/lib',
    'Stof'             => __DIR__.'/../vendor/bundles', 
    [...]
    ));
```

At last, I add annotate my entity

```
/**
 * @var datetime $updatedAt
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="updated_at", type="datetime")
 * @Gedmo:Timestampable(on="update")
 */
private $updatedAt;
```

But I have this error :

> Fatal error: Class 'Gedmo\Timestampable\TimestampableListener' not found in /Symfony/app/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php on line 203

What do I do wrong ?

Comment: The tutorial says you have to use `\` instead of `:`. Do that and clear your cache.

Comment: @ greg0ire. I can't believe I lost 2 hours on that stupid error. Thanks for all. That's works...

Comment: I tried some formatting in my comment but the backslash seems to escape the backtick, I meant "\" instead of `:`

Comment: I had a second error, namespace Gedmo was bad, I edited. So I thing the real error was on that line : 
`'Gedmo' => __DIR__.'/../vendor/doctrine-extensions/lib'`,
But if I put `@Gedmo:Timestampable` instead of `@Gedmo\Timestampable`, it doesn't work either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `@Gedmo\Timestampable(on="update")` and putting the right path when registering the namespace seems to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

For Symfony 2.0.x and Doctrine 2.1.x. projects you'll need to specify the compatible versions of the extensions in deps, this is what worked for me:

```
[DoctrineExtensions]
    git=https://github.com/l3pp4rd/DoctrineExtensions.git
    target=/gedmo-doctrine-extensions
    version=origin/doctrine2.1.x

[StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle]
    git=https://github.com/stof/StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle.git
    target=/bundles/Stof/DoctrineExtensionsBundle
    version=1.0.2
```